# Create model when it depends on another model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm a bit confused about how to create an event in my `createRecord` action, when I'm returning in the route 3 models:

```
return RSVP.hash({
  event: this.store.createRecord('event'),
  hiws: this.store.findAll('hiw'),
  tips: this.store.findAll('tip')
});
```

`Event` is what I want create, but I'm making an `each` in the `hiws` and `tips` in the `hbs`, because one `event` has one `hiw` and one `tip`... like this:

```
<select class="tables__sidebar-select">
  {{#each model.tips as |tip|}}
    <option class="tables__sidebar-option">{{tip.name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
<select>
```

And the same with `hiws`.
I'm trying like this:
inside my `createRecord` action I have:

```
  let hiws = this.get('model.hiws');
  let tips = this.get('model.tips');
  let notify = this.get('notify');

  let event = this.get('store').createRecord('event', {
    hiws: hiws,
    tips: tips
  });

  event.save()
```

I'm trying to create an event with all the properties plus `hiw` and `tip`, but the selected `hiw` and `tip`.

---

Edit:

Now, I'm trying with:

```
{{view "select" content=models.tips.names value=models.event.tip}}
```

But without success.

Comment: Let me see if I have understood you correctly: you have three models: tips, hiws and event. Then, in your template you want to show two select elements, one for tips and another one for hiws. When a value is selected in each of them, you want those two values to be saved as an event record. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes!!!! I'm trying to follow this now -> http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zezapu and i can see the select with the options correctly, but i can't get the value in my action createRecord :/ @HenryVonfire

Comment: take a look at this https://ember-twiddle.com/78b6a5ea8e8e84e5b2a3

Comment: Just that? Somethings i feel like shit :(. Can you provide me some tip? Should i send the models using Ember.RSVP, or there is a better alternative?

Comment: You are learning (as well as I am) so do not be so rough with yourself ;) `RSVP` is the way recommended in the ember documentation to load more than one model in the same route so it is the correct approach. As in my example, you do not need to create the `event` record in the `model`, you can do it in the action `save` when you are sure that the data is going to be saved.

Comment: Hei, thanks!!! Could you post a answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll post it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to achieve what you want to do: 
https://ember-twiddle.com/78b6a5ea8e8e84e5b2a3